# SqlServices.Install is locking the database?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-membership, integration-testing

I'm trying to do some integration test in a csharp project, I'm using Entity Framework 4.
In the test setup I'm recreating the database with

```
        _container.DeleteDatabase();
        _container.CreateDatabase();
```

And then adding the asp.net membership to the database with

```
       SqlServices.Install(
          "MyDb",
          SqlFeatures.All,
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);
```

Everything works fine in the first test, but the setup for the second test fails, with a message that can't drop the database because is in use.
If I don't try to create the membership structure all the tests works fine.

There is any way to free the database?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

I add Pooling=False in the connection string in the membership configuration and now is working